# Is it okay to use simple past and simple present in the same sentence?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

If I am trying to describe my experience today, which one of these is correct?

*Every time I thought I got it, every time I made it to the point where I was sure I understood it, the market proves me wrong.*

Or

*Every time I thought I got it, every time I made it to the point where I was sure I understood it, the market proved me wrong.*

Notes:
I am convinced that the market will continue to prove me wrong in the future.

Comment: Okay, I think I should use present perfect instead: “The market has proven me wrong”. Correct?

Comment: If you are describing an ongoing situation - "Every time I think I [have] got it, every time I make it to the point where i am sure I understand it, the market proves me wrong."

Comment: Generally speaking, irregular verbs tend to slowly become regular. I must admit I'm surprised to discover that [*American* English in particular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+proven%2Chas+proved&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) seems to be primarily responsible for pushing the "irregular" verb form ***has proven*** into pole position (beating out ***has proved***, which always used to be the more common version). To me, it sounds more like dialect (esp., *Scottish*) or "legalese", rather than a natural mainstream usage.

Comment: I questioned the repetition of 'every time' more then the mixed tenses, but that wasn't your question which I think you have answered yourself

Answer (score 0):

If it is universal truth then you can use present tense as subordinate clause with past tense as main clause

Answer (score 0):

The first sounds very informal about something that happened often **in the past**, but neither sentence is correct to describe your context of "my experience today".

Using all present tense is the most natural way to talk about this situation.